# Wordpress email configuration in Plesk panel

Tags: wordpress, email, plesk

We have a wordpress installation in a Plesk panel hosted in windows server.
We using `wp_email()` to send customized emails in our theme files but the email sending function works in some other hosting but fails in plesk panel.

How to configure the correct ports to send successful emails?

Answer (score 0):

Plesk doesn't allow unauthorized mail sending.

You can create mail account in Plesk UI and send email to localhost:25 with authorization which can be configured  via WordPress Plugin as described here:

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/send-emails-with-smtp.htm

or via domain's "PHP settings" > "Additional directives" as described here http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mail.php:

```
smtp_server=127.0.0.1
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=username
auth_password=password
```

and use wp_mail() as general.

Comment: Is there any way without a plugin? We use plesk only for hosting purposes.

Comment: You can set sendmail host and auth in PHP settings via domain's "PHP settings" > "Additional directives"

Comment: Which username to be used in `auth_username=username`? Actually webmail id / server is set up in another hosting account. Do we put it's credentials?